# Combining data from multiple APIs

Tags: php, api-design

I have 2 API's, a Company API and a News API.  I want to extract News related to a Company so what would be the best practice for achieving this?

### Idea 1

- Client - requests /company/[slug]
- Company API - returns company data (including company id)
- Client - requests /news/company/[id]
- Company API - returns news data for company

In this case the client has to make a request to both API's to get the list of news for a company.

### Idea 2

- Client - requests /company/[slug]/news
- Company API - works out company id and forwards request onto News API adding in the company id filter
- News API - returns news data for desired company
- Company API - passes the response form the new API up to the client.

In this instance only 1 request is made from the client and everything desired is returned in the 1 response

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanna do that with an database and you were using Doctrine: What would you do?

Exactly! Build an Entity for that issue:

```
class Company {
    /*
     * @ORM\OneToMany(...)
     */
    private $news;
}
```

Now if you want to get the company with the id 1 and its news you'd do something like this:

```
$company = $entityManager->find('Company', 1);
$news    = $company->getNews();
```

The problem ist that Doctrine can't be used with REST APIs. But there's a driver for Doctrine that is working with REST APIs. This should do the trick:

https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver

```
/*
 * @DataSource\Select("http://yourapi.com/company/{id}")
 */
class Company {}

/*
 * @DataSource\Select("http://yourapi2.com/news/{id}")
 */
class News {}
```

Comment: Thank Tobias, The DoctrineRestBundle looks quite interesting.  Ultimately, what I'm getting from your example is you would get the company data first and then make a second request to get the news data (Idea 1).  This is probably easier to work with from an N+1 perspective if you needed to get news data for multiple companies.